# Can't downgrade my Conky to make it work properly

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, budgie

I know that some people here have asked about the same issues in conky.I thought I've found the answer but conky don't let me do a downgrade to make skins work properly.I read the Corey Goldberg's tips but when I type `sudo gdebi conky-std_1.9.0-4_amd64.deb` my system says that this pack cannot be uninstalled.`Breaks existing package 'conky-all' conflict: conky-std ( )` I don't know even what is conky-std yet! When I type `apt-cache policy conky-std` the results are:`conky-std:
  Instalado: (nenhum)
  Candidato: 1.10.8-1
  Tabela de versão:
     1.10.8-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages`
 I hope someone help me with this issue cause Conky is the one reason that I decided to move to Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: I searched more about my problem and I did a downgrade with success!But it still have a lot of skins that don't works.I need to download the most of skins that I liked and the most of then don't came here or they're not have shown on my desktop! Can anyone tell me what is the correct version to conky works fine in my system? Thanks.